# Парсинг гугла при помощи BeautifulSoup (извлечение количества поисковой выдачи)

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Всем привки в этом чатике. Сразу признаюсь - я тот еще чайник, поэтому если у вас будут полезные замечания - обязательно их озвучьте, спасибо)

В общем задумка - частотная проверка через выдачу гугла (т.е смотрим сколько выдачи у того или иного запроса и на этом основании делаем что то с инфой).

< div id="result-stats"> Результатов: примерно 18 100

Вот так в коде страницы выглядит то что мне нужно и что нужно оттуда вытащить.

Увы, ни один гайд по супу не описывает извлечение подобного рода инфы.. ну я что,я попытался.

Во-первых в самом супе этой строчки почему-то нет. Извлекаю вот так:

```
url = 'https://google.com/search?q={0}'.format(zapros) # url страницы 
 
r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

test=soup.find_all("dev", id="result-page")
```

Есть подозрение что r.content просто не содержит эту строку
Передавал просто r - выдает ошибку - что то там про len функцию

Второе подозрение - нигде так и не пояснили в чем прикол двух аргументов в find_all и как они работают. Подозреваю что я не только неправильно извлек суп, так еще и неправильно по нему ищу.

Добрый странник цифро-маг, помоги, а!

Answer (score -1):

короче разобрался
достаточно было открыть суп как r.text
и извлечь
soup.find(id='result-stats')

и все заработало. Оставляю коммент на всякий случай если кому-то еще придет в голову подобное